# To-Do list saving items to database using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a to-do list that kinda works, but when the page refreshed all of the added items get removed.

At first I tried using local storage to store and then retrieve the items, but I couldn't get that to work. Then I remembered about ajax, but I'm still a beginner and am not familiar with it.

I couldn't find a solution that works, but any tips would be much appreciated.

**Html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog=="
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Shopping List</title>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="logout.php">
        <button class="logout">Logout</button>
    </a>
    
        <header>
            <h1>Shopping List</h1>
        </header>

        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter products" class="todo_input" />
            <button class="todo_button" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="select">
                <select name="todos" class="filter_todo">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="completed">In cart</option>
                    <option value="uncompleted">Not in cart</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="todo_container">
            <ul class="todo_list">
                <div class="todo">
                    <li class="todo_item">Tomatoes</li>
                    <button class="complete_btn"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
                    <button class="delete_btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                </div>   
            </ul>
        </div>

    <script src="script.js" type="application/javascript"></script>           

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo_input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo_button');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo_list');
const filterOption = document.querySelector('.filter_todo');

//event listeners
todoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo)
todoList.addEventListener("click", deleteCheck)
filterOption.addEventListener("click", filterTodo)

//functions
function addTodo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //todo DIV
    const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    todoDiv.classList.add('todo'); 

    //todo LI 
    const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
    newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
    newTodo.classList.add('todo_item');
    todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
    if(todoInput.value === ""){
        return null
    }

    //check mark BUTTON
    const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
    completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
    completedButton.classList.add('complete_btn')
    todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);

    //delete BUTTON
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
    deleteButton.classList.add('delete_btn')
    todoDiv.appendChild(deleteButton);

    //Append to Actual LIST
    todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);

    //Clear todo input VALUE
    todoInput.value = ""
}

//DELETE & CHECK
function deleteCheck(e) {
    const item = e.target;

    //DELETE ITEM
    if (item.classList[0] === "delete_btn") {
        const todo = item.parentElement;

        //ANIMATION TRANSITION
        todo.classList.add("fall")
        todo.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
            todo.remove()
        })
    }

    //COMPLETE ITEM
    if (item.classList[0] === "complete_btn") {
        const todo = item.parentElement;
        todo.classList.toggle("completedItem")
    }
}

//FILTERING THE TASKS ACCORDING THE OPTION
function filterTodo(e) {
    const todos = todoList.childNodes;
    for(let i = 1; i<todos.length; i++ ){
        switch (e.target.value) {

            case "all":
                todos[i].style.display = "flex";
                break;

            case "completed":
                if (todos[i].classList.contains('completedItem')) {
                    todos[i].style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    todos[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                break;
                
            case "uncompleted":
                if (!todos[i].classList.contains('completedItem')) {
                    todos[i].style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    todos[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome here. Well if you're not familiar with Ajax then you can start an online tutorial to learn, try to implement that for your use case and if you got stuck somewhere post that specific issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax as an option to send requests to save your data in you Database and get your records to fill the list for example.
the syntax is a little bit simple:

```
            var data = ($("#YOUR_HTML_FORM_ID").serialize());
            $.ajax({
                url: 'YOUR_API_ROUTE',
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function ( data ) {
                    // All good here, do something like show a success message
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                    // something went wrong

                }
            });
```